# Find index in array that does not have a null value

Tags: java

I have an array called e, this array contains objects, but not on every index. So I'm using a for-loop to find the first index in the array that contains an object. I do this by looking for values that is not null. If I find it, I save the index in a variable called index and break out of the loop. If no index that does not have a null values was found, I want to return from the method. Else, I want to continue and use the variable index that contains an index of the array.

```
int index;

for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i] != null) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

// if index did not get any value inside the for-loop, return

// And here I use the index that was found using the for-loop
```

How can I check if the variable index got a new index from the for-loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a boolean variable and set it to true before you break.

Answer (score 7):

This is one reason to always initialize your variables. If you initialize, you can do things with the value (and avoid unnecessary boolean flags)

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i] != null) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index == -1) return;
```

Comment: This is a more succinct version if Ivaylow's solution, and requires no additional bool flag - A negative index value indicates no value has been found.

Comment: I did not choose this option as if you have several such loops in a row you will not have the effect that the value of index is not changed. However I agree that in case one has a single loop this should do.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Your solution is certainly not wrong, but I think this is cleaner in this specific scenario. Obviously it depends on your exact situation.

Comment: @durron597 never stated you said it is wrong. I just added my comment to point future readers to a possible reasons why this approach may not be the best in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean flag, initialize it to false before the loop and only set it to true in the if block with the break statement. After the loop check the flag's value.

Answer (score 0):

default the index to -1 then check if its > -1

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i] != null) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index >= 0) {


}
```